# Better solutions for a 2em-dash

Tags: macros, punctuation

For anonymization, I want to remove people's names. I have read that the 2em-dash is fine for this. Since there's no `----` for that, I googled a bit about the options.

There's a [source](https://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb24-2/tb77wilson.pdf) (TUGboat, Volume 24 (2003), No. 2
) that suggests the definition of `\iiemdash`:

```
\newcommand*{\iiemdash}{%   2em dash
\rule[0.5ex]{2em}{0.4pt}}
```

However, I compared that to the em-dash (`---`) and find that they are not on the same height:

[image: Rule vs emdash]

[@Dr. Manuel Kühner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14649/dr-manuel-kuehner) asked why the position is important for me. From a graphic design perspective, I think it looks better, just in case different dashes occur on the same line. If `--` and `---` are on the same height, what would the reason be to have the 2em-dash on a different height?

[@alephzero](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/72690/alephzero) suggested that I could adapt the position to my font. However, if there's a font-independent solution, I'd prefer that.

Then I thought about simply using 2 em-dashes:

```
\newcommand*{\iiemdash}{------}
```

which looks fine. I noticed I had trouble with the following spaces, so I added a `\`.

```
\newcommand*{\iiemdash}{------\ }
```

I used it for a while - until one of the redacted names caused a line break.

I fixed this using an additional `\mbox`:

```
\newcommand*{\simple}{\mbox{------}\ }
```

At the moment, this works for me. However, having had all the problems already, I wonder whether there's something else to consider - and of course I'd like to know how a pro would define a 2em-dash.

Comment: **1)** What is the problem with the first solution? --> Why is the different height compared to `---` a problem? **2)** * I noticed I had trouble with the following spaces* --> maybe have a look at the `xspace` package.

Comment: Why not just change the `0.5ex` in the `\iiemdash` to match the em-dash in your font?

Comment: If you can use xetex or luatex, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e3a/fontsupport.htm will show you the fonts on your system that support the omission dash.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: 1) if `--` and `---` and on the same height, why should the 2em-dash differ from that? 2) thanks.

Comment: @alephzero: I'd prefer a solution that is independent of the font.

Comment: @Thérèse: Ok, a Unicode 2em-dash is considerable. It's font-independent (at least theoretically).

Answer (score 6):

In order to be safe with every font, I suggest to use *three* em-dashes, so they superimpose each other. With Computer Modern, two em-dashes overlap finely.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\iiemdash}{%
  \makebox[2em][s]{---\hss---\hss---}%
}

\begin{document}

\hspace*{2em} (empty space 2em wide)

------ (two em-dashes)

\iiemdash\ (2em dash)

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might use [`\xspace`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/xspace.pdf), but it's simpler adding `\` (control space) when a space is needed.

Comment: +1. Now I "have" to google \hss :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner `\hss` is the same as `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil minus 1fil`, so it's glue that (stretches and) shrinks as much as needed.