# Very long dashes in Victorian-era book

Tags: punctuation

I am trying to faithfully recreate the typographic style of a Victorian era book. One thing I've noticed is the extensive use of dashes: em-dashes are everywhere, for example.

Beyond the em dash however, I notice a set of even longer dashes. For example the dash used to indicate a pause in conversation due to a sudden interruption is about 1.5 times the length of an em dash. A similarly long dash is used to indicate the missing part of a name, e.g. "He traveled by horse to W-----".

How can I go about defining and working with dashes longer than an em dash. I can't seem to find any information on the web? I'm using XeLaTeX for my work.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447557 If your fonts support it, you can use Unicode’s omission dash.

Comment: For those wondering why old books do that in the first place, it's discussed on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9479/156845).

Comment: If your goal is to _faithfully recreate_ the typography of the original book, wouldn't it be more accurate to use a series of dashes? I believe that's what was typically used at the time, as Victorian-era typesetters wouldn't have had access to sorts (i.e, special pieces of movable type) for abnormally long dashes either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can superimpose two em-dashes:

```
\newcommand{\emmdash}{---\kern-0.5em---}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\emmdash}{---\kern-0.5em---}

\begin{document}

``He traveled by horse to W\emmdash”

-- --- \emmdash

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: At first you suggested something like `\hbox to 1.5em{---\hss---}`. Is there a significant difference between both methods?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The current version respects possible kernings with characters before and after the dash.

Comment: The overlaid portions appear somewhat darker.

Comment: @AlexG Artifact. I added a high resolution screenshot.

Answer (score 17):

You can use a Latex "rule" to create a thin rectangle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
He travelled by horse to W\rule[0.5ex]{3em}{0.5pt}
\end{document}
```

[image: He travelled by horse to W------]

the format is `\rule[raise]{width-x}{thickness-y}` ([source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts))and this can of course be used in a `\newcommand` for convenience.

By using "ex" and "em" units, the rule should scale nicely with the font.